# div refresh without click of the button

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh

how do i make the div refresh, say after 10 secs and execute the run_query() function without clicking on the button?

```
<script src="scripts/ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 



<div id="quote"><strong>Quote of the Day</strong></div>
<div><a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="run_query()">Next quote …</a></div>
```

Comment: Every 10 seconds or after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use **[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)** function.

```
setInterval(function(){run_query();}, 10000);
```

For the initial load you can do that from the server side code.

Comment: @fusion: Well you can run the function once after page load: `winodw.onload = function(){run_query()}`

Comment: @felix, did that. now it doesn't even refresh every 10 sec .. 
`<script type="text/javascript">
    winodw.onload = function(){
 run_query();
 }
    setInterval(run_query, 10000);
</script>` neither does it load nor refresh.

Comment: There is a typo in window. Its window and not winodw.

Comment: @fusion: In such cases, using Firebug for Firefox is really helpful to find syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout("run_query()",10000);
```

Comment: That runs the function only once after 10 seconds.

Comment: he dosent say that he want to run his function every 10 seconds