# Refresh div ONLY with jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been going through so many posts about this but I can't find anything that works for me.

I'm trying to refresh ONLY A div section NO PHP files. The languages that I'm coding in are Javascript, jQuery, Bootstrap, and CSS.

This is the section I want to refresh 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58207615/5413196

Yes, it's my post I just don't want to recreate the same info again...

Because there is a Split function in an array of images that if you click on it the first image goes behind all of them.

Example array = [1,2,3,4] User clicks [2,3,4,1] but the DOM request is only loaded once on that section and after the user clicks the second click doesn't return the 2nd image behind [3,4,1,2]

I Understand that a DOM is only loaded once but I would really like it if I can find a way with Javascript or jQuery to refresh the div on click or auto-refresh after X seconds so that the user can click on an image again...

**Provide background including what you've already tried**

```
Scowered the whole StackOverflow for answers
```

Some refresh code I tried

[Refresh DIV With Javascript Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407368/refresh-div-with-javascript-button)

[Refresh only one div with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581007/refresh-only-one-div-with-ajax)

[div refresh without click of the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629327/div-refresh-without-click-of-the-button)

[Refresh div without load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252987/refresh-div-without-load)

[refresh only one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866670/refresh-only-one-div)

[Onclick refresh only div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959641/onclick-refresh-only-div)

Any assistance would be amazing

Thanks in advance
Faz

*EDIT*

I was asked to add the code from the other post.

```
let image_arr = [{
    id: 'part_1',
    image_src: 'http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals?t=1570040444517',
    h6_tag: 'Bradley Hunter',
    p_tag: 'Based in Chicago. I love playing tennis and loud music.',
    pin: 'a',
  },
  {
    id: 'part_2',
    image_src: 'http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals?t=1570040444516',
    h6_tag: 'Marie Bennet',
    p_tag: 'Currently living in Colorado. Lover of art, languages and travelling.',
    pin: 'b',
  },
  {
    id: 'part_3',
    image_src: 'http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals?t=1570040444515',
    h6_tag: 'Diana Wells',
    p_tag: 'Living in Athens, Greece. I love black and white classics, chillout music green tea.',
    pin: 'c',
  },
  {
    id: 'part_4',
    image_src: 'http://placeimg.com/100/100/animals?t=1570040444514',
    h6_tag: 'Christopher Pierce',
    p_tag: 'Star Wars fanatic. I have a persistent enthusiasm to create new things.',
    pin: 'd',
  },
];

$(document).ready(function () {
  // create
  createPartnerRow(image_arr);
  // set image background
})

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[id^=part_]").hover(function (image_arr) {
      $(this).addClass('border')
    },
    function () {

    });
});

$("[id^=part_]").ready(function () {
  $("[id^=part_]").click(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('border')
    // set value
    var current_partner = image_arr[0];
    // remove first element from array
    image_arr = image_arr.splice(1, 4);
    // append current_partner to end of array
    image_arr.push(current_partner);
    // clear the row of all partners;
    $('#part_1, #part_2, #part_3, #part_4').remove();
    // recreate row
    console.log(image_arr);
    createPartnerRow(image_arr);
  });
})


function createPartnerRow(image_arr) {
  for (i = 0; i < image_arr.length; i++) {
    $('#partner_row').append(
      '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 p-3" id="' + image_arr[i].id + '">' +
      '<button class="border-0 bg-white">' +
      '<div class="facebox"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="' + image_arr[i].image_src + '"' + '/><span class="pin">' + image_arr[i].pin + '</span></div>' +
      '<h6 class="text-center g-mt-50 font-weight-bold pt-2">' + image_arr[i].h6_tag + '</h6>' +
      '<p class="text-center g-mt-50 pt-2">' + image_arr[i].p_tag + '</p>' +
      '</button>' +
      '</div>'
    )
  }
}
```

```
#partner_row {display:flex;}
.bg-white {background: transparent;}
.facebox{
position:relative;
display:inline-block; margin:auto;
width:80px; font-size:0;
}
.facebox .rounded-circle{
width:100%; border-radius:50%;
}
.facebox .pin {
display:block;
width:22px;
height:22px;
border:3px solid white;
border-radius:50%;
background:blue;
position:absolute;
bottom:-3px;
right:-3px;
  color:white; text-align:center; font-size:13px; line-height:20px;
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="partner_row"></div>
```

Comment: _"I just don't want to recreate the same info again"_  I understand where you're coming from but it makes it difficult to understand switching between questions. Please try to keep questions self-contained. It's best if you can include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within your question

Comment: @Phil Sorry thought that It would be appreciated. Will remember it for the future

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to be amazed with a nice DOM system, try React...but...for what you're looking for: have you tried changing the innerHTML.

-so you target the element with an onclick function (addEventListener in JS or add onclick in the HTML)
-then you give your div an id like `<div id="myDiv"></div>`
-then in the onclick target fucntion/event listener target function you use :

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = 
`<div>` +
`  <p>write whatever html you want in here</P>` +
`</div>`;
```

you dont need to reload the whole DOM, just change the innerHTML of the element you want. there are a few ways to do this, but i think this might be the best bet for you. let me know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the `'#part_1`, `#part_2`, `#part_3`, `#part_4` elements (along with their hover and click event handlers) are destroyed then re-rendered on every rotation.

Hence second and subsequent clicks don't work.

There's a number of ways to cope with this:

1. Reattach event handlers after re-rendering.
2. Delegate event handling to the static container, `#partner_row`.
3. Render `#partner_row` once then rotate the images non-destructively by DOM manipulation, ensuring that the event handlers remain attached.

Approach 3 will has an additional advantage of being far more efficient than rotating the array and re-rendering from scratch. Here it is in full:

```
$(function () {
    var $partnerRow = $('#partner_row');

    // Render partners as a side effect of mapping image_arr to an array of jQuery objects,
    // then wrap to make a jQuery set.
    $(image_arr.map(function(imgData) {
        $('<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 p-3" id="' + imgData.id + '">' +
        '<button class="border-0 bg-white">' +
        '<div class="facebox"><img class="rounded-circle img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="' + imgData.image_src + '"' + '/><span class="pin">' + imgData.pin + '</span></div>' +
        '<h6 class="text-center g-mt-50 font-weight-bold pt-2">' + imgData.h6_tag + '</h6>' +
        '<p class="text-center g-mt-50 pt-2">' + imgData.p_tag + '</p>' +
        '</button>' +
        '</div>').appendTo($partnerRow);
    }))
    .hover(function() { // permanently attach event handlers to the rendered elements
        $(this).addClass('border');
    }, function () {
        // $(this).removeClass('border'); // ???
    }).on('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('border');
        // rotate images non-destructively by DOM manipulation
        $partnerRow.find('.col-md-3.col-sm-6.p-3').eq(0).appendTo($partnerRow); // selector may simplify.
    });
});
```